# Adding articles don't works PHP

Tags: php, addition, article

```
<?php

session_start ();

include_once ('../include/connection.php');

if (isset ( $_SESSION ['logged_in'] )) {

    if (isset ( $_POST ['title'], $_POST ['content'] )) {
        $title = $_POST ['title'];
        $content = $_POST ['content'];

        if (empty ( $title ) or empty ( $content )) {
            $error = 'All fields are required';
        } else {

            $query = $pdo->prepare ( 'INSERT INTO articles (article_title, article_content, article_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' );

            $query->bindValue ( 1, $title );
            $query->bindValue ( 2, $content );
            $query->bindValue ( 3, time () );

            $query->execute ();

            header ( 'Location: index.php' );
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Cannot help without knowing the error.

Comment: no error don't submit form i dont now why

Comment: <form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

   <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" /> <br /> <br />
   <textarea rows="15" cols="50" placeholder="Content" name="content"></textarea>
   <br /> <br /> <input type="submit" value="Add Article" />
  </form>

Comment: I suggest you first var_dump the $_POST variables first to see if your form is submitting, then do the DB insert and redirect respectively.

Comment: @СтелиянСтоянов You form works correctly for me. I received the data in $_POST array. Your error is caused by something else - not the form.

Comment: problem fix my DB don't work correcly

Answer (score 0):

please check your syntax - "}" is missing

maybe this solved the problem